# ItemsControl child property not to get parent's datacontext

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datacontext, itemscontrol

I have a property in my view-model:

```
public BitmapImage MyImage {get; set;}
```

I have an ItemsControl, whose items have a few images and some text. One of the images in the items of the itemscontrol should be MyImage. However, the ItemsControl has an ItemsSource property which I set to binding Path=Result, and I know that all of the items in the itemscontrol take the data context of Result.

So, now when I make this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=MyImage}"  />
```

Of course, I get the error:

```
BindingExpression path error: 'MyImage' property not found on 'object' ''KeyValuePair`2' (HashCode=-853042223)'. BindingExpression:Path=MyImage; DataItem='KeyValuePair`2' (HashCode=-853042223); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')
```

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 :

This happens because MyImage is direct property, and the binding doesn't search for direct properties. Instead it searches in the data context of the parent.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: *This happens because MyImage is direct property, and the binding doesn't search for direct properties. Instead it searches in the data context of the parent*... I think that you're mistaken. That error simply means that there is no `MyImage` property on the object that is set as the `DataContext` of the `DataTemplate` that your `Binding` resides in. You just need to change your `Binding Path` and I think that @pushpraj may have provided you with  the correct path that you need.

Answer (score 1):

use RelativeSource here

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" />
```

this is how you can access the parent's DataContext in the item's template etc.

---

**EDIT**

I just thought of another possible problem with the binding, seems like you are binding a dictionary of the elements

if the image path is in one of the key or value then perhaps this is the solution

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=Key.MyImage}" />
```

or

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=Value.MyImage}" />
```